# click event fired although classname changed

Tags: jquery

I have a newbie question about jQuery. Why is it that I can trigger the click event below even though the element has changed class? Even though I change the class from "edit" to "tide", $(".edit").click() is working on that element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".edit").click(function(){
                console.log(this);
                $(this).removeClass("edit").addClass("tide");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="edit">Hi there</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that behavior, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edit").live('click', function(){
        console.log(this);
        $(this).removeClass("edit").addClass("tide");
    });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xj9Ue/).  As it is now, `$(".edit")` finds elements that match the `.edit` selector **at that time** and binds to them, those `click` event handlers are in no way dependent upon the class name after that.  With [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) the selector is evaluated at the time of the event, so it *does* matter.

Answer (score 1):

The click event is bound to the element, not the class. In your example you are selecting elements based on the `edit` class, and then attaching a click event to those elements. Once attached to the element it stays attached until explicitly removed, regardless of future changes to the element's CSS class.

As Nick Craver points out, jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method may do what you want here.